# How to populate Python's dictionary data into Latex's table?

Tags: tables, python, dictionaries

I have the data filled up at run-time in the dictionary.
Need help in populating this data to a table in Latex.

Code snippet for table:

```
f.write('\\end{itemize}\n')
f.write('\\begin{table}[ht]')
f.write('\\caption{Resolved issues}')
f.write('\\centering')
f.write('\\begin{tabular}{c c} ')
f.write('\\hline\\hline')
f.write(' Issue-Id & Summary \\\ [0.5ex] ')
f.write('\\hline ')
f.write(' 123 & Summary1 \\\ ')
f.write(' 456 & Summary2 \\\  [1ex] ')
f.write('\\hline ')            
f.write('\\end{tabular}')
f.write('\\label{table:nonlin}')
f.write('\\end{table}')
```

I have hard-coded Issue-id to 123 and 456. Similarly Summary as Summary1 and Summary2.

My dictionary content is like this:

```
{'35871': ['Bad Loop Optimizations'], '35398': ['Bad long loop expansion], '36702': ['Crash reading a file']}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)
For what I understand, your question seems more related to python than to TeX!

Try the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Shanthi = {'35871': ['Bad Loop Optimizations'], '35398': ['Bad long loop expansion'], '36702': ['Crash reading a file']}

with open("./Shanthi.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write('\\begin{table}[ht]\n\\caption{Resolved issues}\n\\centering\n')
    f.write('\\begin{tabular}{@{}c c@{}}\n\t\\toprule\n\t{\\bfseries Issue-Id} & {\\bfseries Summary} \\\\\n\t\\midrule\n\t')
    f.write("\\\\ \n\t".join(["{} & {}".format(_k, ", ".join(_v)) for _k, _v in sorted(Shanthi.items())]))
    f.write('\\\\\n\t\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n\\label{table:nonlin}\n\\end{table}')
```

It produces a `Shanthi.tex` file containing:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Resolved issues}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c c@{}}
    \toprule
    {\bfseries Issue-Id} & {\bfseries Summary} \\
    \midrule
    35398 & Bad long loop expansion\\ 
    35871 & Bad Loop Optimizations\\ 
    36702 & Crash reading a file\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
```

Thus you can use `\input{Shanthi.tex}` in your `main` file.
Be sure to add `\usepackage{booktabs}` in your preamble to have a nice table ([see here for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343511/making-nice-tables)).

### Small enhancements proposed by `projetmbc`

([f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) are usable only with python ≥ 3.6)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

Shanthi = {
    '35871': ['Bad Loop Optimizations'], 
    '35398': ['Bad long loop expansion'], 
    '36702': ['Crash reading a file']
}

with open("./Shanthi.tex", "w") as f:
    backreturn = "\\\\\n" + " "*8

    content = backreturn.join([
        f"{_k} & {', '.join(_v)}" 
        for _k, _v in sorted(Shanthi.items())
    ])

    f.write(f"""
\\begin{{table}}[ht]
    \\caption{{Resolved issues}}
    \\centering
    \\begin{{tabular}}{{@{{}}c c@{{}}}}
        \\toprule
        {{\\bfseries Issue-Id}} & {{\\bfseries Summary}} \\\\
        \\midrule
        {content}\\\\
        \\bottomrule
    \\end{{tabular}}
    \\label{{table:nonlin}}
\\end{{table}}
    """.strip())
```

---

### To handle large cell contents, long table and Id-duplicates

Just use `longtable` instead of `table` + `tabular`, with a `p`-column (or `m`). Replace the dictionary by a list of tuples.

Your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Shanthi = [
    ('35871', 'Bad Loop Optimizations'),
    ('35398', 'Bad long loop expansion'),
    ('36702', 'Crash reading a file'),
    ('2692415', 'connect fatal error : System  Mixing wild card named port connection (.*) and position wrong while instanced with signals concatenated and tool generated "option.f"'),
    ('35871', 'Bad Loop Optimizations'),
    ('35398', 'Bad long loop expansion'),
    ('36702', 'Crash reading a file'),
    ('2692415', 'connect fatal error : System  Mixing wild card named port connection (.*) and position wrong while instanced with signals concatenated and tool generated "option.f"'),
    ('35871', 'Bad Loop Optimizations'),
    ('35398', 'Bad long loop expansion'),
    ('36702', 'Crash reading a file'),
    ('2692415', 'connect fatal error : System  Mixing wild card named port connection (.*) and position wrong while instanced with signals concatenated and tool generated "option.f"'),
    ('0', '\\lipsum[1]'),
    ('35871', 'Bad Loop Optimizations'),
    ('35398', 'Bad long loop expansion'),
    ('36702', 'Crash reading a file'),
    ('2692415', 'connect fatal error : System  Mixing wild card named port connection (.*) and position wrong while instanced with signals concatenated and tool generated "option.f"'),
]

with open("./Shanthi.tex", "w") as f:
    backreturn = "\\\\\n" + " "*4

    content = backreturn.join([
        f"{_tuple[0]} & {_tuple[1]}" 
        for _tuple in Shanthi
    ])

    f.write(f"""
\\begin{{longtable}}{{@{{}}cp{{.7\\textwidth}}@{{}}}}
    \\caption{{Resolved issues\\label{{table:nonlin}}}}\\\\
    \\toprule
    {{\\bfseries Issue-Id}} & {{\\bfseries Summary}} \\\\ \\midrule
    \\endfirsthead
    \\caption{{Resolved issues (continued)}}\\\\
    \\toprule
    \multicolumn{{2}}{{l}}{{\\scriptsize\\emph{{\\ldots{{}} continued}}}}\\\\
    {{\\bfseries Issue-Id}} & {{\\bfseries Summary}} \\\\ \\midrule
    \\endhead
    \\multicolumn{{2}}{{r}}{{\\scriptsize\\emph{{to be continued\ldots}}}}\\\\
    \\bottomrule
    \\endfoot
    \\bottomrule
    \\endlastfoot
    {content}\\\\
\\end{{longtable}}
    """.strip())
```

It produces a `Shanthi.tex` file you call in a `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \input{Shanthi.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton!! :)

Comment: This is adding duplicates to the table. Issue-Id Summary
    1 Shared IO flow

    1 Shared IO flow
    2 serial sims fail
    3 gives miscompares

    1 Shared IO flow
    2 serial sims fail
    4 Hangs
    3 gives miscompares

Comment: @Shanthi I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I get the output in the following format. With repeated table entries.`Issue-Id     Summary`   
 `35398        Bad long loop expansion `  
 
  `35398        Bad long loop expansion `  
  `35871        Bad Loop Optimizations `  
 
  `36702        Crash reading a file `  
  `35398        Bad long loop expansion `  
  `35871        Bad Loop Optimizations `  
 
  `33213        Hangs `  
   `36702        Crash reading a file`

Comment: If you have duplicates on keys, maybe you need a list/tuple of lists/tuples instead of a dictionary.

Comment: @Shanthi I have proposed an easier-to-maintain code.

Comment: @projetmbc thanks a lot for the [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I didn't know this tool. However, it's only for python ≥ 3.6

Comment: BTW, I'm curious why you remove the `coding utf8` line? I do add it since I (always) code in French with accented letters.

Comment: The table gets generated. but if table contents are big, it should span to next line. But this is not happening. it is getting truncated.

Comment: Do you mean some cells content are to "big" (use a `p` column instead a `c` column)? Or the whole table need to span over several pages (use a `longtable` instead)?

Comment: Both.. Some cells are big and whole table will span over 2-3 pages."longtable" is giving error. 9: Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\caption): `c' used.    `f.write('\\begin{longtable}[ht]\n\\caption{Issue-Id}\n\\centering\n')
                f.write('\\begin{tabular}{@{}l l@{}}\n\t\\toprule\n\t{\\bfseries STAR-id} & {\\bfseries Summary} \\\\\n\t\\midrule\n\t')
                f.write("\\\\ \n\t".join(["{} & {}".format(_k, ", ".join(_v)) for _k, _v in sorted(dict.items())]))
                f.write('\\\\\n\t\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n\\label{table:nonlin}\n\\end{longtable}')`

Comment: Using longtable is not helping. Long sentences are still trucated in cells.                                   
`f.write('\\begin{longtable}{@{}l l@{}}')`
`f.write('\\caption{Resolved '+doc_name+' STARs}\\\\')`
`f.write('\\begin{tabular}{@{}l l@{}}\n\t\\toprule\n\t{\\bfseries STAR-id} & {\\bfseries Summary} \\\\\n\t\\midrule\n\t')`
`f.write("\\\\ \n\t".join(["{} & {}".format(_k, ", ".join(_v)) for _k, _v in sorted(dict.items())]))`
`f.write('\\\\\n\t\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n\\label{table:nonlin}\n\\end{longtable}') `    Any suggestions??

Comment: @Nbur Default `utf8` encoding is conventional for the moment. A froggy french too.

Comment: @Shanthi Add a problematic input and the unwanted output in your question so as to help you efficiently.

Comment: This is the output from the table.                                                                      
`2692415 connect fatal error : System  Mixing wild card named port connection (.*) and position wrong while instanced with signals concatenated and tool generated "option.f"`                                                                                                                        
As you can see, the cell has large data and does not fit into a single line in the table. The code I used for the table is mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @Shanthi see the edit.

Comment: @Shanthi It is possible using the package `ninja` to work with a standard `LaTeX` code for the template. If you are interested I can add an answer just to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

Just an aside on

> Code snippet for table:

> f.write('\end{itemize}\n')

> f.write('\begin{table}[ht]') ...

Your Python code can become more readable and easier to maintain, when you 1) concatenate your desired output into one long string, and 2) write this out once. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp for details, and some Python-pseudo code on this strategy, leaving potential backslashing problems as they are:

```
% assembling all required output
s = '\\end{itemize}\n'
s += '\\begin{table}[ht]'
s += '\\caption{Resolved issues}'
s += ...
% ...
f.write(s) % that's all, folks. "Just one f.write" (Like in 'The hunt for red october')
```

Best wishes

Comment: Hi, My issue is still active. Can anyone help me here. I have created new post at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611273/table-with-large-cell-data-and-long-table-spanning-over-multiple-page

Answer (score 0):

The answer by NBUR takes in a list of tuples, instead of a dict. The question asks for converting a dict to a LaTex table. Below is the adapted code to directly go from dict to latex table:

```
def dict_to_latex_table(params:dict,key_header:str,value_header:str,caption:str):

    tuples=dict_to_latex_tuples(params)
    with open("latex/Tables/params_table.tex", "w") as f:
        backreturn = "\\\\\n" + " "*4

        content = backreturn.join([
            f"{_tuple[0]} & {_tuple[1]}" 
            for _tuple in tuples
        ])
    
        f.write(f"""
\\begin{{longtable}}{{@{{}}cp{{.7\\textwidth}}@{{}}}}
    \\caption{{{caption}\\label{{table:nonlin}}}}\\\\
    \\toprule
    {{\\bfseries {key_header}}} & {{\\bfseries {value_header}}} \\\\ \\midrule
    \\endfirsthead
    \\caption{{{caption} (continued)}}\\\\
    \\toprule
    \multicolumn{{2}}{{l}}{{\\scriptsize\\emph{{\\ldots{{}} continued}}}}\\\\
    {{\\bfseries {key_header}}} & {{\\bfseries {value_header}}} \\\\ \\midrule
    \\endhead
    \\multicolumn{{2}}{{r}}{{\\scriptsize\\emph{{to be continued\ldots}}}}\\\\
    \\bottomrule
    \\endfoot
    \\bottomrule
    \\endlastfoot
    {content}\\\\
\\end{{longtable}}
    """.strip())



def flatten_dict(some_dict:dict):
    flat_dict={}
    # Flatten dict
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            for newKey, newValue in value.items():
                flat_dict[newKey] = newValue
        else:
            flat_dict[key]=value
    print(f'flattend_params={flat_dict}')
    return flat_dict
    
def dict_to_latex_tuples(some_dict: dict):
    flat_dict=flatten_dict(some_dict)
    tuples=[]
    for key,value in flat_dict.items():
        if isinstance(key,str):
            key=key.replace("_"," ")
        if isinstance(value,str):
            value=value.replace("_"," ")
        tuples.append((key,value))
    return tuples
```

Also, the column headers and caption have been parameterized. And it replaces underscores with spaces.