# Table with large cell data and long table spanning over multiple page

Tags: pdf, longtable, tabularx, pandoc, python

I need to create a 2-column table with below requirements:

1. Column 2 has large data which spans over 2-3 lines
2. Entire table may span over 2-3 pages

The table entries are stored in a dictionary and should be populated at run-time.
Can anyone help me out?
Below is my code..

```
                f.write('\\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}')
                f.write('\\caption[stars]{Resolved '+doc_name+' STARs} \label{stars}\n')
                f.write('\\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\\textbf{STAR}} & \\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\\textbf{Description}}\n')
                f.write('\\endfirsthead\n')  

                f.write('\\multicolumn{2}{c}%{{\\bfseries \\tablename\ \\thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\')
                f.write('\\hline \\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\\textbf{STAR}} & \\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\\textbf{Description}} \\\ \hline')
                f.write('\\endhead\n')
                
                f.write('\\hline \\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline')
                f.write('\\endfoot\n')
        
                f.write('\\hline \\hline')
                f.write('\\endlastfoot')
                f.write('\\n')
                f.write("\\\\ \n\t".join(["{} & {}".format(_k, ", ".join(_v)) for _k, _v in sorted(dict.items())]))
                
                f.write('\\end{longtable}')
```

Comment: The standard column types (`r,l,c`) are for single-lined cells. You probably should use the  `xltabular` package and its eponymous environment,, which brings the functionalities (and syntax) of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: I suggest doing the table first as pure Latex-document. Perhaps you may want to use \usepackage{makecell} ? See https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell for details. // Once that works, put it into python. // Se also "Related" links to the right.

Comment: simplest change is to change `ll` to `p{5cm}p{5cm}` or whatever width you want, but please post code here as latex examples, not  fragments of python that would write latex