# Difficulty in using multicolumn or multirow in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I just started learning latex and needed a kind of table like what the uploaded picture shows. The code was generated by Excel2LaTex. I have tried some ways but cannot make it.

Several cells in the lower left corner of the table are merged. The command `\tabular` cannot make the table adaptively adjust the width to the whole row. If I use `\resizebox`, the height of the table will increase together, which will be very unsightly. So I used `\tabularx` but it always went wrong...Although I knew that `\tabular` cannot be simply replaced by `\tabularx`, I had no idea dealing with it...

So I come here for help. By the way, if it is really difficult, the big fork in the big cell can not be used. After all, this is drawn by Excel and it is very simple there.

[image: The table I need]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    order & number & weight & order & number & weight \\
    \hline
    1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    \hline
    2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\
    \hline
    3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3 \\
    \hline
    ...   & ...   & ...   & ...   & ...   & ... \\
    \hline
    118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118 \\
    \hline
    119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119 \\
    \hline
    120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{}} & ...   & ...   & ... \\
    \cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}      & 138   & 138   & 138 \\
    \cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}      & 139   & 139   & 139 \\
    \cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}      & 140   & 140   & 140 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I also tried [tablesgenerator website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables). It gave me the following code:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{order} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{number} & weight & order & number & weight \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}      & 1      & 1     & 1      & 1      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}      & 2      & 2     & 2      & 2      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}      & 3      & 3     & 3      & 3      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}    & ...    & ...   & ...    & ...    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{118}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{118}    & 118    & 118   & 118    & 118    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{119}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{119}    & 119    & 119   & 119    & 119    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{120}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{120}    & 120    & 120   & 120    & 120    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{}}                            & ...   & ...    & ...    \\ \cline{4-6} 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                                             & 138   & 138    & 138    \\ \cline{4-6} 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                                             & 139   & 139    & 139    \\ \cline{4-6} 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                                             & 140   & 140    & 140    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

---

@Mico: I didn't know how to insert a lot of code into the comments, so I answered my own question here. It's just an information table and I want it to look better. The following code has integrated Mico's code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,longtable}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of X col. type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Fast Hankel Transform} \label{FHT}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{C|}}
\hline
Order     & Abscissa of $J_0$    & Weight of $J_0$       & Order      & Abscissa of $J_1$    & Weight of $J_1$         \\\hline
1         & $-19.32$             & $9.63\times10^{-7}$   & 1          & $-18.21$             & $-6.77\times10^{-14}$   \\\hline
2         & $-19.11$             & $-5.02\times10^{-6}$  & 2          & $-18.01$             & $3.40\times10^{-13}$    \\\hline
3         & $-18.90$             & $1.25\times10^{-5}$   & 3          & $-17.81$             & $-7.43\times10^{-13}$   \\\hline
$\vdots$  & $\vdots$             & $\vdots$              & $\vdots$   & $\vdots$             & $\vdots$                \\\hline
118       & $5.04$               & $6.23\times10^{-6}$   & 118        & $5.49$               & $7.33\times10^{-6}$     \\\hline
119       & $5.25$               & $-1.12\times10^{-6}$  & 119        & $5.69$               & $-3.76\times10^{-6}$    \\\hline
120       & $5.46$               & $1.04\times10^{-7}$   & 120        & $5.89$               & $1.86\times10^{-6}$     \\\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}             {\multirow{4}{*}{}}     & $\vdots$   & $\vdots$             & $\vdots$                \\
\cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                    & 138        & $9.54$               & $-1.36\times10^{-9}$    \\
\cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                    & 139        & $9.74$               & $3.53\times10^{-10}$    \\
\cline{4-6}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                    & 140        & $9.94$               & $-4.54\times10^{-11}$   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! So where is your problem: provided codes compile fine? If you really want to use diagonals in the huge cell, maybe you can try to use a TiKz matrix. BTW, I suggest to have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343511/making-nice-tables) (and its answers!) in order to make nicer table than with excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. Both take up the full width of the textblock. The first uses a `tabularx` environments (with centered versions of the `X`column type), and the second uses a `tabular*`-inspired `longtable` environment.

The two major differences between the tables is that second (a) gets rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines in order to give the table a more open and inviting "look" and (b) allows page breaks, as needed, which may be useful since the real table may have as many as 140 rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,longtable}  
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A ``prison window''-look table} \label{tab:addlabel1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{C|}}
    \hline
    order & number & weight & order & number & weight \\
    \hline
    1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    \hline
    2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\
    \hline
    3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3 \\
    \hline
    \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    \hline
    118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118 \\
    \hline
    119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119 \\
    \hline
    120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120 \\
    \hline
    &&& \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \cline{4-6}
    &&& 138   & 138   & 138   \\ \cline{4-6}
    &&& 139   & 139   & 139   \\ \cline{4-6}
    &&& 140   & 140   & 140   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begingroup % localize scope of next 4 instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}   % see p. 7 of user guide of longtable package
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c} }

    %% information about headers and footers
    
    \caption{A table with a much more open ``look''} \label{tab:addlabel2}\\
    \toprule
    order & number & weight & order & number & weight \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable, cont'd}\\
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    order & number & weight & order & number & weight \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize \em cont'd on following page}\\
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    %% body of longtable
    
    1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\ 
    2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\
    3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3     & 3 \\ 
    $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
    118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118   & 118 \\
    119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119   & 119 \\
    120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120   & 120 \\
    &&& $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
    &&& 138   & 138   & 138 \\
    &&& 139   & 139   & 139 \\
    &&& 140   & 140   & 140 \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to incorporate additional information provided by the OP: Here's a variant of the `tabularx`-based solution which (a) allows columns 1 and 4 to be narrower than columns 2, 3, 5, and 6 and (b) allows the numbers in the latter four columns to be aligned on their decimal markers, with the help of the `S` column type provided by the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,gensymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of X col. type
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C|}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
\caption{Fast Hankel Transform} \label{FHT}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| *{2}{ c | S[table-format=-2.2] |S[table-format=-1.2e-2]| } }
\hline
Order & \mC{Abscissa of $J_0$} & \mC{Weight of $J_0$} &
Order & \mC{Abscissa of $J_1$} & \mC{Weight of $J_1$} \\
\hline
1         & -19.32   &  9.63e-7  & 1          & -18.21     & -6.77e-14   \\ \hline
2         & -19.11   & -5.02e-6  & 2          & -18.01     &  3.40e-13   \\ \hline
3         & -18.90   &  1.25e-5  & 3          & -17.81     & -7.43e-13   \\ \hline
{$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} \\ \hline
118       &   5.04   &  6.23e-6  & 118        &   5.49     &  7.33e-6    \\ \hline
119       &   5.25   & -1.12e-6  & 119        &   5.69     & -3.76e-6    \\ \hline
120       &   5.46   &  1.04e-7  & 120        &   5.89     &  1.86e-6    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} \\ \cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & 138        & 9.54       & -1.36e-9   \\ \cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & 139        & 9.74       &  3.53e-10  \\ \cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & 140        & 9.94       & -4.54e-11  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tend to use the first one because the latter has a different style from my tables in article although it does look comfortable. But the first table will have a problem in my article, which is different from my other tables using `\tabularx`. That is, each horizontal line `\hline` will extend infinitely to the right of the paper, even if the rightmost content of the table is over. I don't know why my `\textwidth` is almost infinite. In contrast, my other tables do not have this problem probably because `\multicolumn` is not used.

Comment: @happyboat - I'm afraid I have idea how or why horizontal lines might "extend infinitely to the right". Please provide more information about what you're doing.

Comment: I studied my mistakes for some time. It turned out that I didn't notice the important code in the third line at the beginning, which made a little joke. And I have a further question. Now these six columns seem to be of equal width. In the actual table, the data recorded in each column of mine is not the same length, so I hope they can be unequal in width, but with no line breaks. How to modify such code? I don't know whether LaTeX can be intelligent enough, because it means that it can automatically allocate the width to each cell without manual adjustment, while ensuring no line breaks.

Comment: I don't know if you saw the code I pasted in my answer, but I've learned to share the code with you in the comments, which Diaa taught me. [Code Link](https://pastebin.com/4ANga07M)

Comment: I'm grateful to you for answering my question detailedly and patiently. I've learned a lot of useful things and successfully solved the difficulties. Thank you again and wish you all the best.